# Unable to create the MYSQL EXECUTE command by using dynamic no. of user defined variables (prevent sql-injectiondatabase-mysql)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, sql-injection, execute

I have been trying to execute the prepare statements using the dynamic number of user defined variables but I could not find any example which solves my problem.

I have a mysql stored-procedure which accepts more than 15 parameters. Based on the input parameters' value, the query's condition gets added/removed to/from the procedure. So user defined variables should also gets changed as per the condition added to the proc. So, is there any way to execute the proc using dynamic no of user defined variables?

Here is my sample stored procedure,

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `aaa`$$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `aaa`(IN param1 VARCHAR(255),IN param2 VARCHAR(255), IN param3 VARCHAR(255)
                      ,IN param4 VARCHAR(255),IN param5 VARCHAR(255),IN param6 VARCHAR(255),
                      IN param7 VARCHAR(255),IN param8 VARCHAR(255),IN param9 VARCHAR(255),
                      IN param10 VARCHAR(255)
                     )
BEGIN
    SET @v1 = param1;
    SET @v2 = param2;
    SET @v3 = param3;
    SET @v4 = param4;
    SET @v5 = param5;
    SET @v6 = param6;
    SET @v7 = param7;
    SET @v8 = param8;
    SET @v9 = param9;
    SET @v10 = param10;

    BEGIN

    SET @QUERY = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM test.customer where name= 'abcd' ");
    IF param1 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field1 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param2 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field2 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param3 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field3 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param4 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field4 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param5 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field5 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param6 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field6 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param7 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field8 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param8 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field8 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param9 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field9 = ? ");
    END IF;

    IF param10 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,"  AND field10 = ? ");
    END IF;



PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY;
EXECUTE stmt using @v1,@v2,.......; -- varies based on the condition satisfied. can we make this dynamic??
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


END;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
SET @QUERY = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM test.customer where name= ''abcd'' ');
IF param1 IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,'  AND field1 = ? ');
ELSE
    SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,'  AND ? IS NULL');
END IF;

IF param2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,'  AND field2 = ? ');
ELSE
    SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,'  AND ? IS NULL');
END IF;

...same for the other params...

PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY;
EXECUTE stmt using @v1, @v2, @v3, @v4, @v5, @v6, @v7, @v8, @v9, @v10;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This solution allows the EXECUTE to accept the same number of arguments. Some of them will be tested against the column, otherwise they will be tested with `IS NULL` which will be true, because we only use that predicate if we already know they are NULL.

Note I also changed `"` to `'`. I recommend against using `"` for string delimiters because the meaning can change depending on your SQL_MODE.

Comment: Thank you so much.I am thinking there might be a way to avoid the else conditions. Anyways this helps me lot.